# Get stack trace from errors using mongoose without calling .exec()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I recently read in the mongoose docs that to get a stack trace from mongoose errors that includes details about which file the mongoose code was called from, you need to call .exec()?

#### Example:

I currently have a lot of code using this structure:

```
await collection.deleteMany({});
```

Do I need to add .exec() to get a more helpful stack trace?

```
await collection.deleteMany({}).exec();
```

If so, is there a global workaround, so I don't have to add .exec() a countless number of times?

##### References:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8747

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't get proper stack traces with `await` without using `.exec()`.

This is elaborated on [in another issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8691) referenced in the GitHub issue you linked:

> `await Model.findOne()` without `exec()` will unfortunately remove the calling file from the stack trace because of how V8's `await` handles custom thenables.

You can also see this in [the source for `Query.prototype.then`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/e90aab12bf3ced0d0ac7b5994a0530f77fc9f8e5/lib/query.js#L4591-L4609), which calls `exec()` under the hood, then calls `.then()` on its result, which prevents JavaScript from tracing the error back to your code.

As a result, there is no workaround for this, and you will need to either migrate your codebase to using `exec()`, or hope the Node.js engine is improved to better handle this at some point.